# Dock and Menu Bar Disappear in OS X El Capitan When in App Window

Tags: macos

I have a Macbook Pro 11,1 running OS X El Captian. Recently, whenever in an application such as Firefox my menu bar and dock disappear. This is really annoying, as in system preferences both my dock & menu bar are set to not autohide. If I click the desktop, suddenly the dock and menu bar pop back up.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the Firefox menu bar disappear as well? Are you running Firefox in Fullscreen-Mode? What happens if you just move the mouse to the top of the screen (with Firefox still the active application)?

Comment: I believe it's a bug. What are you doing specifically when it disappears? I have the same issue when watching videos driven by the silverlight player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug with Firefox. These instructions I found fixed the issue.

> 1. In Finder right click on the Firefox app and select “Show Package Contents”
> 2. Navigate to Contents and open “Info.plist” in TextEdit.
> 3. In this file, near the top, there should be a piece of text that says < dict >, underneath this add the following making sure all of the
>      text is present.
>
>    ```
>    <key>LSUIPresentationMode</key>
>    <integer>0</integer>
>    ```
> 4. Save that file
> 5. Restart Firefox
> 6. Happy browsing again

src: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3096551?tstart=0